# How to print elements in list n times

Tags: python, list

I have a list [0, 4, 1, 2, 3]. I would like to print each element the same number of times as its value, each time on a new row and under each other. Expected output:

```
[0, 4, 1, 2, 3]
    4  1  2  3
    4     2  3
    4        3
    4
```

Here is my failed attempt to code. I'm very new to Python, so apologies for what is probably a very rookie question. Hope somebody can help me in the right direction.

```
list = [0, 4, 1, 2, 3]
print(list)
for x in range(len(list)):
    for y in range(list[x]):
        print(x * " ", end="")
        print(list[x], end="")
    print()
```

My code gives me this output:

```
[0, 4, 1, 2, 3]

4 4 4 4
  1
   2   2
    3    3    3
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: presently this does sound rather like 'write my code for me'... hint: `for _ in range(x)` is a handy paradigm

Comment: @2e0byo `for item in list` is an even more handy paradigm

Comment: hah, true.  I was thinking of the repetitive steps.  but now we're writing the code in the comments ;)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Sorry, I`m a bit new to this. I have added my (failed) code in the post now

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
my_list = [0, 4, 1, 2, 3]
for i in range(1, len(my_list)):
    for e in my_list:
        if e >= i:
            print(f"{e} ", end="")
        else:
            print("  ", end="")
    print()
```